# In iTunes 11, is it possible to show the genre of an album in Artist view?

Tags: itunes

In iTunes 11 I use the artist view. In artist view, I see the artists on the very left, then the album covers and the track multi-columned at the right side of the cover. Is it possible to also show the genre of the album?

The only way I know to access the genre is to right-click the cover or a track, open "information" and look at "Genre".

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: **NO**

Apple has custom view options screens for Artist, Albums, Genres views and therefore you cannot change the columns beyond what they allow. It seems it is only available in song and playlist view.

I am guessing the reason for this is that the artist view is meant to group and display a specific set of data. I would suspect in future versions they may introduce the ability to do this, however for the moment it is not possible.

Sidenote: The View Options screen has been drastically modified for the song view compared to the previous version.